# MYSQL: selecting rows that contain duplicate data in given rows (primary-key check w/o primary-keys)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, primary-key

I have quite big table, let's call it MyTable.

Let it look like this:

guid, container, container_slot, something, something_2, something_3

I would like to get a select result of duplicates, but with 3-column-check.

Let me explain it in more convenient way:

```
guid, container, container_slot, something, something_2, something_3
1,    1,         1,              5,         2,           1
1,    1,         2,              63,        5,           2              (!)
1,    1,         2,              12,        2,           63             (!)
1,    1,         3,              1,         2,           63
1,    2,         5,              64,        2,           63
2,    1,         1,              34,        8,           21
2,    1,         3,              2,         1,           25
```

Everything here is OK, except two records,  those with (!) at the end.

In normal table I would set guid, container and container_slot as primary keys, to prevent those (!) lines.

But this table is huge and it would really make it slow.

I would like to select those two lines, where:

```
guid, containter, container_slot
```

are duplicated at the same moment, and all other slots can be whatever.

so:

```
guid, container, containter_slot
1,    1,         2
1,    1,         3
```

Are OK, but:

```
1,    1,         2
1,    1,         2
```

Are duplicated.

Is there any way to give me result as this? :

```
guid, container, container_slot, something, something_2, something_3
1,    1,         2,              63,        5,           2
1,    1,         2,              12,        2,           63
```

Comment: Why do you think a PK will be slow on this table?

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my mytable x WHERE x.guid = mt.guid AND ... AND ...);`

Comment: @Charleh: Well. Maybe because this table has 16.321.341 rows and nearly 100.000 queries per second. :P

Comment: That's not a reason to not put a PK on it - 100,000 queries per second might actually be helped by indexes/PK if the indexes cover the queries... not sure how MySQL does it exactly but I'd imagine that you are storing a heap rather than a clustered index and therefore depending on your workload it may actually be beneficial to put a PK on http://kejser.org/clustered-indexes-vs-heaps/ - though like I said, depending on workload your mileage may vary. Worth testing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select guid, container, container_slot
from mytable
group by guid, container, container_slot
having count(1) > 1
```

That will give all duplicate rows by their key.  Turn it into a subquery and inner join to function as a filter

```
select mytable.* from
(select guid, container, container_slot
from mytable
group by guid, container, container_slot
having count(1) > 1)a
inner join mytable on mytable.guid = a.guid and mytable.container = a.container and mytable.containerslot = a.containerslot
```

where in / where exist queries work too...mysql handles them poorly and increases run time, so I tend to use the inner joining methodology

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xOekUiE.png
As you can see it works but partialy.
Results are quite messed. Hard to read. And because of that I don't really know if that result is proper.

//edit
Nevermind, just sorted them. x)